# ValueError: No data provided for "conv2d_input". Need data for each key in: ['conv2d_input']

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

When I use a [malaria](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/malaria) dataset for create a simple CNN with tensorflow, in python, with jupyter notebooks, I have this Error: `ValueError: No data provided for "conv2d_input". Need data for each key in: ['conv2d_input']`.

[This is my github repository with the code](https://github.com/srdantas/conv-malaria/blob/master/notebook.ipynb)

This is my code for create a model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=[103, 103, 3]),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And the sumary:

```
Model: "sequential_12"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 103, 103, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_24 (MaxPooling (None, 51, 51, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 51, 51, 64)        9280      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_25 (MaxPooling (None, 25, 25, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_12 (Flatten)         (None, 40000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_36 (Dense)             (None, 128)               5120128   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_37 (Dense)             (None, 32)                4128      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_38 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 5,134,017
Trainable params: 5,134,017
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And the fit:

```
model.fit(
    train,
    steps_per_epoch=train_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validate,
    validation_steps=validate_size
)
```

Maybe this is a error:

```
ValueError: in converted code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py:677 map_fn
        batch_size=None)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py:2410 _standardize_tensors
        exception_prefix='input')
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py:510 standardize_input_data
        'for each key in: ' + str(names))

    ValueError: No data provided for "conv2d_input". Need data for each key in: ['conv2d_input']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `tfds.load('malaria', split='train[0%:70%]', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)`.

`as_supervised=True` will make the dataset return `(image, label)` instead of `dict(image=, ...)`